# Section spans across multiple pages. How do I remove heading at top left of the next page?

Tags: sectioning

I am working on a paper and have a section (Section 2) and 2 subsections. The section is declared on page 1, and subsection 2.1 also only spans page 1. On page 2 I have subsection 2.2 but because the section spans 2 pages, it displays the name of the heading italicized on the top left of page 2.

If I have a page break before I declare the section it doesn't do that, but I would rather not have a page break. How do I remove the italicized heading?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I suspect something like `\markboth{}{}` but without example it's only a guess

Comment: If all you want is to remove it, \thispagestyle{plain}.